# Find the sum of the series $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{-n}(n+3)}{(n+1)(n+2)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the sum of $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{-n}(n+3)}{(n+1)(n+2)}$

Comment: As long as you need the value: $\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\frac{2^{-n}(n+3)}{(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac{2^{-n}}{n+1}-\frac{2^{-(n+1)}}{n+2}$$
and then telescope.

Comment: I think it should be $\frac{2^{-n}(n+3)}{(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac{2^{1-n}}{n+1}-\frac{2^{-n}}{n+2}$

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{2^{-n}n}{n+1} = 2^{-n} - \dfrac{2^{-n}}{n+1}$

Also: $\dfrac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} = \dfrac{1}{n+1} - \dfrac{1}{n+2}$